# Invalid RSS feed error when change 'settings->reading' from summary to full text in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, mailchimp

I change settings->reading from summary to full content in wordpress,
when I create campaign in mailchimp on the very first step when I enter RSS feed URL it gives error 'is not a valid RSS feed'.but when it is set to summary in wordpress,campaign gets created without error.

Comment: And what's your question? Have you tried validating the feed using another validator that gives you more insight about that error?

Comment: yes I try to validate feed in https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi, it gives error like
1. content:encoded should not contain sizes attribute 
2.content:encoded should not contain preload attribute
3.content:encoded should not contain controls attribute
how to deal with these errors?

Comment: So, then it's obvious: the generation of your RSS feed is broken. There is no connection to MailChimp.

Comment: okay so rewriting RSS feed is the solution right?